# Recursive JS function with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, loops, recursion

I have the following code

```
var data = [
  { id: "0" },
  {
    id: "1",
    children: [
      {
        id: "1.1",
        children: [
          {
            id: "1.1.1",
            children: [
              {
                id: "1.1.1.1",
                children: [
                  { id: "1.1.1.1.1" },
                  { id: "1.1.1.1.2" },
                  { id: "1.1.1.1.3" }
                ]
              },
              { id: "1.1.1.2" },
              { id: "1.1.1.3" }
            ]
          },
          { id: "1.1.2" },
          { id: "1.1.3" },
        ]
      },
      { id: "1.2" },
      { id: "1.3" }
    ]
  },
  { id: "2" },
  { id: "3" }
];

function recursive(current) {
  var first = current[0];
  current.shift();
  var remaining = current;

  console.log(first.id);

  if (first.children) {
    setTimeout(function(){
      recursive(first.children);
    })
  }

  if (remaining.length) {
    setTimeout(function(){
      recursive (remaining);
    });
  }
}

recursive(data);
```

This output is not in order because of the setTimeout

[image]

Question:

1. How can I change it to output the something like in the image below?
2. How do I know the last iteration in this recursive function? I need to run something once the list is exhausted.

I **cant** use forEach because I **have** to use setTimeouts for a different reason. I understand setTimeout does not work properly in a loop. Any ideas????

Desired output:

[image]

Comment: Why do you have to use `setTimeout`?

Comment: I need to render some UI elements on the screen after X iterations which does not work without setTimeouts :(

Comment: Give the function a callback and use it. Or better, make it return a promise.

Comment: What would be the condition to call the callback?

Comment: The desired output you just posted is not breadth-first.

Comment: I am sorry, I should have just posted the image rather than using some term I don't fully understand. Do you mind giving it another look? Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking when you want to do breadth-first iteration, you need to use a queue (ie. FIFO). Javascript doesn't have a native queue data structure, so this just uses an array and `shift`, but it still gets the job done.

Here you just push everything into the queue at each level. This insures the children get pushed in after the parents, and therefore you iterate over the parents first. Normally with a graph you would also keep track of where you've been, but since this is a tree, there are no loops.

```js
var data = [ { id: "0" }, { id: "1", children: [ { id: "1.1", children: [ { id: "1.1.1", children: [ { id: "1.1.1.1", children: [ { id: "1.1.1.1.1" }, { id: "1.1.1.1.2" }, { id: "1.1.1.1.3" } ] }, { id: "1.1.1.2" }, { id: "1.1.1.3" } ] }, { id: "1.1.2" }, { id: "1.1.3" }, ] }, { id: "1.2" }, { id: "1.3" } ] }, { id: "2" }, { id: "3" } ];

function recursive(queue) {
  var current = queue.shift();
  if (current === undefined) return
  console.log(current.id)
  if (current.children) {
    current.children.forEach(node => {
      queue.push(node)
    })
  }
  setTimeout(function() {
    recursive(queue)
  })
}

recursive(data);
```

EDIT - FOR DEPTH FIRST:

If you want depth first you basically use a stack rather than a queue. Here it's a little strange because you care about the order of the children, so we load the stack backwards.

```js
var data = [ { id: "0" }, { id: "1", children: [ { id: "1.1", children: [ { id: "1.1.1", children: [ { id: "1.1.1.1", children: [ { id: "1.1.1.1.1" }, { id: "1.1.1.1.2" }, { id: "1.1.1.1.3" } ] }, { id: "1.1.1.2" }, { id: "1.1.1.3" } ] }, { id: "1.1.2" }, { id: "1.1.3" }, ] }, { id: "1.2" }, { id: "1.3" } ] }, { id: "2" }, { id: "3" } ];
  
function recursive(stack) {
    let current = stack.pop()
    if (current === undefined) return
    console.log(current.id)
    if(current.children)  {
        stack.push(...current.children.reverse())
    }
    setTimeout(function(){
        recursive(stack)
    })
}
recursive(data.reverse());
```

Comment: Thanks but I think this gives me Depth first rather than Breadth-first. I have attached the desired out now to the question.

Comment: @ManishPradhan I see: 0, 1, 2, 3, 1.1, 1.2 etc. That's breadth first.

Comment: I am sorry, I should have just posted the image rather than using some term I don't fully understand. Do you mind giving it another look? Appreciate your help.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You're a life saver.

Answer (score 4):

**Tangled wires**

Recursion and asynchrony are separate concepts but there's no reason we can't use them together. First, we'll look at some synchronous traversals then add support for asynchrony as we go. I like this style of answer because we get to see the same program represented in multiple ways. We focus on a *small* changes that deliver *big* impact.

We start with one approach using generators —

```js
const Empty =
  Symbol ()

const breadthFirst = function* ([ node = Empty, ...nodes ])
{
  if (node === Empty)
    return
  else
    (yield node, yield* breadthFirst (nodes.concat (node.children || [])))
}

const data =
  [{ id: "0" },{id: "1",children: [{id: "1.1",children: [{id: "1.1.1",children: [{id: "1.1.1.1",children: [{ id: "1.1.1.1.1" },{ id: "1.1.1.1.2" },{ id: "1.1.1.1.3" }]},{ id: "1.1.1.2" },{ id: "1.1.1.3" }]},{ id: "1.1.2" },{ id: "1.1.3" },]},{ id: "1.2" },{ id: "1.3" }]},{ id: "2" },{ id: "3" }]

for (const x of breadthFirst (data))
  console.log (x.id)
  
// 0 1 2 3 1.1 1.2 1.3 1.1.1 ... 1.1.1.1.3
```

Collect all the `id` fields in an array

```
const values =
  Array.from (breadthFirst (data), x => x.id)

console.log (values)
// [ '0', '1', '2', '3', '1.1', '1.2', ... '1.1.1.1.3' ]
```

Alternatively, we can make `breadthFirst` a higher-order function, much like `Array.prototype.map` or `Array.prototype.reduce`

```js
const Empty =
  Symbol ()

const breadthFirst = (f = identity, [ node = Empty, ...nodes]) =>
  node === Empty
    ? []
    : [ f (node), ...breadthFirst (f, nodes.concat (node.children || [])) ]

const data =
  [{ id: "0" },{id: "1",children: [{id: "1.1",children: [{id: "1.1.1",children: [{id: "1.1.1.1",children: [{ id: "1.1.1.1.1" },{ id: "1.1.1.1.2" },{ id: "1.1.1.1.3" }]},{ id: "1.1.1.2" },{ id: "1.1.1.3" }]},{ id: "1.1.2" },{ id: "1.1.3" },]},{ id: "1.2" },{ id: "1.3" }]},{ id: "2" },{ id: "3" }]
  
const values =
  breadthFirst (x => x.id, data)
  
console.log (values)
// [ '0', '1', '2', '3', '1.1', '1.2', ... '1.1.1.1.3' ]
```

We could make `breadthFirst` an asynchronous function using Promise

```
const breadthFirst = (f = identity, [ node = Empty, ...nodes]) =>
  node === Empty
    ? Promise.resolve ([])
    : breadthFirst (f, nodes.concat (node.children || [])) .then (answer => [ f (node), ...answer ])

const promiseOfValues =
  breadthFirst (x => x.id, data)

promiseOfValues.then (console.log, console.error)
// [ '0', '1', '2', '3', '1.1', '1.2', ... '1.1.1.1.3' ]
```

Lastly, we can make the user-supplied function `f` asynchronous as well

```
const breadthFirst = (f = identity, [ node = Empty, ...nodes]) =>
  node === Empty
    ? Promise.resolve ([])
    : Promise.resolve (node) .then (f) .then (value =>
        breadthFirst (f, nodes.concat (node.children || [])) .then (answer =>
          [ value, ...answer ]))

const promiseOfValues =
  breadthFirst (x => new Promise (r => setTimeout (r, 250, x.id)), data)

promiseOfValues.then (console.log, console.error)
// => Promise
// 4 seconds later ...
// [ '0', '1', '2', '3', '1.1', '1.2', ... '1.1.1.1.3' ]
```

Lastly again lol, use the new `async`/`await` syntax

```
const breadthFirst = async (f = identity, [ node = Empty, ...nodes]) =>
{
  if (node === Empty)
    return []

  const value =
    await Promise.resolve (node) .then (f)

  const answer =
    await breadthFirst (f, nodes.concat (node.children || []))

  return [ value, ...answer ]
}

const promiseOfValues =
  breadthFirst (x => new Promise (r => setTimeout (r, 250, x.id)), data)

promiseOfValues.then (console.log, console.error)
// => Promise
// 4 seconds later ...
// [ '0', '1', '2', '3', '1.1', '1.2', ... '1.1.1.1.3' ]
```

**Going generic**

Recursion is a functional heritage and functional programming is all about reusability. Above `breadthFirst` takes on many responsibilities. Beyond building the correct sequence the nodes, we need to think about the Promise API and *how* to wire the sequence together; this is a burden and it can be lifted. Below, we can make the process more generic using a *reverse* fold – `unfold`

```js
const unfold = (f, init) =>
  f ( (x, next) => [ x, ...unfold (f, next) ]
    , () => []
    , init
    )

const nextLetter = c =>
  String.fromCharCode (c.charCodeAt (0) + 1)

const alphabet =
  unfold
    ( (next, done, c) =>
        c > 'z'
          ? done ()
          : next (c, nextLetter (c))
    , 'a'
    )

console.log (alphabet)
// [ a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z ]
```

`Array.prototype.reduce` takes a collection of values and *reduces* it to a single value – `unfold` takes a single value and *unfolds* it to a collection of values

```
const fib = (n = 0) =>
  unfold
    ( (next, done, [ n, a, b ]) =>
        n < 0
          ? done ()
          : next (a, [ n - 1, b, a + b ])
    , [ n, 0, 1 ]
    )

console.log (fib (20))
// [ 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597, 2584, 4181, 6765 ]
```

OK, but you wanted *asynchronous* unfolding - simply add the `async` and `await` keywords

```
const asyncUnfold = async (f, init) =>
  f ( async (x, acc) => [ x, ...await asyncUnfold (f, acc) ]
    , async () => []
    , init
    )
```

Let's demo this with a less contrived function, such as an asynchronous `getChildren`. In a real program, this might take a node or a node id and fetch it from a database returning a Promise of the node's children. Below, we see a dramatic reduction in complexity in `breadthFirst`. Note the programmer is not burdened by the complexities of Promise here

```
const getChildren = (node) =>
  new Promise ((resolve, _) =>
    setTimeout (resolve, 250, node.children || []))

const Empty =
  Symbol ()

const breadthFirst = (nodes) =>
  asyncUnfold
    ( async (next, done, [ node = Empty, ...rest ]) =>
        node === Empty
          ? done ()
          : next (node.id, [ ...rest, ...await getChildren (node) ])
    , nodes
    )

breadthFirst (data) .then (console.log, console.error)
// => Promise
// 4 seconds later ...
// [ '0', '1', '2', '3', '1.1', '1.2', ... '1.1.1.1.3' ]
```

As it turns out, you didn't want a breadth-first traversal, you wanted *depth-first*. An advantage of the approaches used here is that we can utilize the same generic `unfold` function for various traversals – below we implement `depthFirst` identical to `breadthFirst` but this time we make one tiny change

```
const breadthFirst = (nodes) =>
const depthFirst = (nodes) =>
  asyncUnfold
    ( async (next, done, [ node = Empty, ...rest ]) =>
        node === Empty
          ? done ()
          // breadth-first
          next (node.id, [ ...rest, ...await getChildren (node) ])
          // depth-first
          : next (node.id, [ ...await getChildren (node), ...rest ])
    , nodes
    )

depthFirst (data) .then (console.log, console.error)
// => Promise
// 4 seconds later ...
// [ '0', '1', '1.1', '1.1.1', '1.1.1.1', '1.1.1.1.1', '1.1.1.1.2', ..., '2', '3' ]
```

**remarks**

A final comment about your `data` is a mistake that many people make when modeling hierarchical trees of data. In your `data` object, each item is a Node, and each item of `children` is a Node; however, `data` itself is not a Node, it is just a plain Array. This inconsistency is a pain point and actually makes your program less versatile.

Remember what I said about fold (`reduce`) and `unfold` above? `reduce` takes a collection and produces *one* value, `unfold` does the opposite. When traversing a tree, we start with a *single node* — not an array of nodes.

```
const breadthFirst = (nodes) =>
const breadthFirst = (node) =>
  asyncUnfold
    ( async (next, done, [ node = Empty, ...rest ]) =>
        node === Empty
          ? done ()
          : next (node.id, [ ...rest, ...await getChildren (node) ])
    , nodes
    , [ node ]
    )

const depthFirst = (nodes) =>
const depthFirst = (node) =>
  asyncUnfold
    ( async (next, done, [ node = Empty, ...rest ]) =>
        node === Empty
          ? done ()
          : next (node.id, [ ...await getChildren (node), ...rest ])
    , nodes
    , [ node ]
    )

breadthFirst ({ id: 'root', children: data }) .then (console.log, console.error)
// => Promise
// 4 seconds later ...
// [ 'root', '0', '1', '2', '3', '1.1', '1.2', ... '1.1.1.1.3' ]

depthFirst ({ id: 'root', children: data }) .then (console.log, console.error)
// => Promise
// 4 seconds later ...
// [ 'root', '0', '1', '1.1', '1.1.1', '1.1.1.1', '1.1.1.1.1', '1.1.1.1.2', ..., '2', '3' ]
```

Complete program demonstration

```js
const asyncUnfold = async (f, init) =>
  f ( async (x, acc) => [ x, ...await asyncUnfold (f, acc) ]
    , async () => []
    , init
    )
    
const Empty =
  Symbol ()
  
const depthFirst = (node) =>
  asyncUnfold
    ( async (next, done, [ node = Empty, ...rest ]) =>
        node === Empty
          ? done ()
          : next (node.id, [ ...await getChildren (node), ...rest ])
    , [ node ]
    )
    
const breadthFirst = (node) =>
  asyncUnfold
    ( async (next, done, [ node = Empty, ...rest ]) =>
        node === Empty
          ? done ()
          : next (node.id, [...rest, ...await getChildren (node) ])
    , [ node ]
    )

const getChildren = (node) =>
  new Promise ((resolve, _) =>
    setTimeout (resolve, 250, node.children || []))

const data =
  [{ id: "0" },{id: "1",children: [{id: "1.1",children: [{id: "1.1.1",children: [{id: "1.1.1.1",children: [{ id: "1.1.1.1.1" },{ id: "1.1.1.1.2" },{ id: "1.1.1.1.3" }]},{ id: "1.1.1.2" },{ id: "1.1.1.3" }]},{ id: "1.1.2" },{ id: "1.1.3" },]},{ id: "1.2" },{ id: "1.3" }]},{ id: "2" },{ id: "3" }]

breadthFirst ({ id: 'foo', children: data }) .then (console.log, console.error)
// => Promise
// 4 seconds later ...
// [ 'foo', '0', '1', '2', '3', '1.1', '1.2', ... '1.1.1.1.3' ]

depthFirst ({ id: 'bar', children: data }) .then (console.log, console.error)
// => Promise
// 4 seconds later ...
// [ 'bar', '0', '1', '1.1', '1.1.1', '1.1.1.1', '1.1.1.1.1', '1.1.1.1.2', ..., '2', '3' ]
```

Comment: thanks but I think I made a mistake take "breadth-first" in my question, I actually wanted something like the image I just attached to the question. Sorry about that.

Comment: @ManishPradhan your mistake opens a door for you to learn how to implement various traversals using generic functions. I've updated my answer with an edit

Comment: Thanks to people like you :)