# Recursion call async func with promises gets Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection

Tags: asynchronous, recursion, fetch, es6-promise

```
const PAGESIZE = 1000;
const DEFAULTLINK = `${URL}/stuff?pageSize=${PAGESIZE}&apiKey=${APIKEY}`;

export const getAllStuff = (initialLink = DEFAULTLINK) => {
  let allStuff = {};
  return getSuffPage(initialLink)
    .then(stuff => {
      allStuff = stuff;
      if (stuff.next) {
        return getAllStuff(stuff.next)
          .then(nextStuff => {
            allStuff = Object.assign({}, stuff, nextStuff);
            return allStuff;
          });
      } else {
        return allStuff;
      }
    });
};

const getSuffPage = nextPageLink => {
  fetch(nextPageLink).then(res => {
    return res.json();
  });
};
```

Calling getAllStuff throws:

Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
    at getAllStuff

I think it is usually because I do not return from a promise then or something but where don't I?

Answer (score 4):

I've been working with [anamorphisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anamorphism) or `unfold` in JavaScript [lately](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49523873/633183) and I thought I might share them with you using your program as a context to learn them in

```js
const getAllStuff = async (initUrl = '/0') =>
  asyncUnfold
    ( async (next, done, stuff) =>
        stuff.next
          ? next (stuff, await get (stuff.next))
          : done (stuff)
    , await get (initUrl)
    )

const get = async (url = '') =>
  fetch (url) .then (res => res.json ())
```

To demonstrate that this works, we introduce a fake `fetch` and database `DB` with a fake `delay` of 250ms per request

```js
const fetch = (url = '') =>
  Promise.resolve ({ json: () => DB[url] }) .then (delay)

const delay = (x, ms = 250) =>
  new Promise (r => setTimeout (r, ms, x))

const DB = 
  { '/0': { a: 1, next: '/1' }
  , '/1': { b: 2, next: '/2' }
  , '/2': { c: 3, d: 4, next: '/3' }
  , '/3': { e: 5 }
  }
```

Now we just run our program like this

```js
getAllStuff () .then (console.log, console.error)

// [ { a: 1, next: '/1' }
// , { b: 2, next: '/2' }
// , { c: 3, d: 4, next: '/3' }
// , { e: 5 }
// ]
```

And finally, here's `asyncUnfold`

```js
const asyncUnfold = async (f, init) =>
  f ( async (x, acc) => [ x, ...await asyncUnfold (f, acc) ]
    , async (x) => [ x ]
    , init
    )
```

Program demonstration 1

```js
const asyncUnfold = async (f, init) =>
  f ( async (x, acc) => [ x, ...await asyncUnfold (f, acc) ]
    , async (x) => [ x ]
    , init
    )

const getAllStuff = async (initUrl = '/0') =>
  asyncUnfold
    ( async (next, done, stuff) =>
        stuff.next
          ? next (stuff, await get (stuff.next))
          : done (stuff)
    , await get (initUrl)
    )

const get = async (url = '') =>
  fetch (url).then (res => res.json ())

const fetch = (url = '') =>
  Promise.resolve ({ json: () => DB[url] }) .then (delay)

const delay = (x, ms = 250) =>
  new Promise (r => setTimeout (r, ms, x))

const DB = 
  { '/0': { a: 1, next: '/1' }
  , '/1': { b: 2, next: '/2' }
  , '/2': { c: 3, d: 4, next: '/3' }
  , '/3': { e: 5 }
  }

getAllStuff () .then (console.log, console.error)

// [ { a: 1, next: '/1' }
// , { b: 2, next: '/2' }
// , { c: 3, d: 4, next: '/3' }
// , { e: 5 }
// ]
```

Now say you wanted to collapse the result into a single object, we could do so with a `reduce` – this is closer to what your original program does. Note how the `next` property honors the last value when a key collision happens

```js
getAllStuff ()
  .then (res => res.reduce ((x, y) => Object.assign (x, y), {}))
  .then (console.log, console.error)

// { a: 1, next: '/3', b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5 }
```

If you're sharp, you'll see that `asyncUnfold` could be changed to output our object directly. I chose to output an array because the sequence of the unfold result is generally important. If you're thinking about this from a *type* perspective, each foldable type's *fold* has an isomorphic *unfold*.

Below we rename `asyncUnfold` to `asyncUnfoldArray` and introduce `asyncUnfoldObject`. Now we see that the direct result is achievable without the intermediate `reduce` step

```js
const asyncUnfold = async (f, init) =>
const asyncUnfoldArray = async (f, init) =>
  f ( async (x, acc) => [ x, ...await asyncUnfoldArray (f, acc) ]
    , async (x) => [ x ]
    , init
    )

const asyncUnfoldObject = async (f, init) =>
  f ( async (x, acc) => ({ ...x, ...await asyncUnfoldObject (f, acc) })
    , async (x) => x
    , init
    )

const getAllStuff = async (initUrl = '/0') =>
  asyncUnfold
  asyncUnfoldObject
    ( async (next, done, stuff) =>
    , ...
    )

getAllStuff ()
  .then (res => res.reduce ((x, y) => Object.assign (x, y), {}))
  .then (console.log, console.error)

// { a: 1, next: '/3', b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5 }
```

---

But having functions with names like `asyncUnfoldArray` and `asyncUnfoldObject` is completely unacceptable, you'll say - and I'll agree. The entire process can be made generic by supplying a type `t` as an argument

```js
const asyncUnfold = async (t, f, init) =>
  f ( async (x, acc) => t.concat (t.of (x), await asyncUnfold (t, f, acc))
    , async (x) => t.of (x)
    , init
    )

const getAllStuff = async (initUrl = '/0') =>
  asyncUnfoldObject
  asyncUnfold
    ( Object
    , ...
    , ...
    )

getAllStuff () .then (console.log, console.error)

// { a: 1, next: '/3', b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5 }
```

Now if we want to build an array instead, just pass `Array` instead of `Object`

```js
const getAllStuff = async (initUrl = '/0') =>
  asyncUnfold
    ( Array
    , ...
    , ...
    )

getAllStuff () .then (console.log, console.error)

// [ { a: 1, next: '/1' }
// , { b: 2, next: '/2' }
// , { c: 3, d: 4, next: '/3' }
// , { e: 5 }
// ]
```

Of course we have to concede JavaScript's deficiency of a functional language at this point, as it does not provide consistent interfaces for even its own native types. That's OK, they're pretty easy to add!

```js
Array.of = x =>
  [ x ]

Array.concat = (x, y) =>
  [ ...x, ...y ]

Object.of = x =>
  Object (x)

Object.concat = (x, y) =>
  ({ ...x, ...y })
```

Program demonstration 2

```js
Array.of = x =>
  [ x ]
  
Array.concat = (x, y) =>
  [ ...x, ...y ]
  
Object.of = x =>
  Object (x)

Object.concat = (x, y) =>
  ({ ...x, ...y })

const asyncUnfold = async (t, f, init) =>
  f ( async (x, acc) => t.concat (t.of (x), await asyncUnfold (t, f, acc))
    , async (x) => t.of (x)
    , init
    )

const getAllStuff = async (initUrl = '/0') =>
  asyncUnfold
    ( Object // <-- change this to Array for for array result
    , async (next, done, stuff) =>
        stuff.next
          ? next (stuff, await get (stuff.next))
          : done (stuff)
    , await get (initUrl)
    )

const get = async (url = '') =>
  fetch (url).then (res => res.json ())

const fetch = (url = '') =>
  Promise.resolve ({ json: () => DB[url] }) .then (delay)

const delay = (x, ms = 250) =>
  new Promise (r => setTimeout (r, ms, x))

const DB = 
  { '/0': { a: 1, next: '/1' }
  , '/1': { b: 2, next: '/2' }
  , '/2': { c: 3, d: 4, next: '/3' }
  , '/3': { e: 5 }
  }

getAllStuff () .then (console.log, console.error)

// { a: 1, next: '/3', b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5 }
```

Finally, if you're fussing about touching properties on the native `Array` or `Object`, you can skip that and instead pass a generic descriptor in directly

```js
const getAllStuff = async (initUrl = '/0') =>
  asyncUnfold
    ( { of: x => [ x ], concat: (x, y) => [ ...x, ...y ] } 
    , ...
    )

getAllStuff () .then (console.log, console.error)

// [ { a: 1, next: '/1' }
// , { b: 2, next: '/2' }
// , { c: 3, d: 4, next: '/3' }
// , { e: 5 }
// ]
```