# Recursive Promises Not Returning

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, promise

I have a recursive function like so

```
function missingItemsPromise() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        if (missingItems == 0) {
            console.log('resolves');
            console.log(products);
            return resolve();
        } else {
            page++;
            url = getUrl(id, page);
            http.get(url, function(xres) {
                xres.setEncoding('utf8');
                xres.on('data', function (xtraBody) {
                    console.log('calling');
                    var xtraJson = JSON.parse(xtraBody);
                    var xtraProducts = xtraJson['products'];
                    products = products.concat(xtraProducts);
                    productsLength = products.length;
                    missingItems = total - productsLength;
                    missingItemsPromise();
                });
            });
        } 
    });
};
```

and I'm using it like

```
getInitial.
then(missingItemsPromise).
then(() => {
 console.log('hello');   
});
```

I'm noticing that the hello never returns because I suspect that I'm creating more than one promise on a recursive call but I"m unsure of how to return out of it.

How can I return each recursively created promise?

EDIT:

```
function missingItemsPromise() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        if (missingItems == 0) {
            console.log('resolves');
            return resolve();
        } else {
            page++;
            url = getUrl(id, page);
            http.get(url, function(xres) {
                xres.setEncoding('utf8');
                xres.on('data', function (xtraBody) {
                    console.log('calling');
                    var xtraJson = JSON.parse(xtraBody);
                    var xtraProducts = xtraJson['products'];
                    products = products.concat(xtraProducts);
                    productsLength = products.length;
                    missingItems = total - productsLength;
                    missingItemsPromise();
                    resolve();
                });
            });
        }
    });
};
```

results in

```
calling
hello <----notice here that it's already resolving once the first call resolve 
is called
calling
calling
resolves
```

Comment: You need to `resolve/reject` in your `else{}` block.

Comment: are you sure no exception is being raised? Why don't you also add a `catch` to check it out?

Comment: i tried adding a resolve after the recursive call but realized that as the other recursive call continues, the outer promise will resolve leading to the hello being called earlier than the recursive function really finishing completely

Comment: In your `else` block, try replacing the two last lines by `missingItemsPromise().then(resolve)`.

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursion is a functional heritage and so using it with functional style yields the best results. That means writing functions that accept and operate on their inputs (rather than relying on external state) and return values (rather than relying on mutation or side effects).

Your program, on the other hand, calls functions without arguments, uses external state `missingItems`, `products`, `productsLength`, `total`, `page` and uses mutations like `page++` and reassignments like `products = ...`, `productsLength = ...`, `missingItems = ...`. We're gonna fix all of this!

I'm just going to blast thru this and hope it sets you on the right track. If you're stuck at the end, I link some other answers which explain the techniques used here in greater detail.

```
const getAllProducts = async (page = 0) =>
  asyncUnfold
    ( async (next, done, [ res, nextPage ]) =>
      res.products.length === 0
          ? done ()
          : next ( res.products                               // value to add to output
                 , [ await getPage (nextPage), nextPage + 1 ] // next state
                 )
    , [ await getPage (page), page + 1 ] // initial state
    )
```

We introduce the `getPage` helper we used above

```
const getPage = async (page = 0, itemsPerPage = 5) =>
  getProducts (page * itemsPerPage, itemsPerPage)
    .then (res => res.json ())
```

Next, for the purposes of this demo, we introduce a fake `getProducts` function, and a fake `DB` where each product is simply a number. We also use `delay` to simulate real network delay.

In your real program, you just need to provide a `getProducts` function that can query products using `offset` and `limit` inputs

```
// fakes used for demonstration below
const getProducts = (offset = 0, limit = 1) =>
  Promise.resolve
    ({ json: () =>
        ({ products: DB.slice (offset, offset + limit) })
    })
  .then (delay)

const delay = (x, ms = 250) =>
  new Promise (r => setTimeout (r, ms, x))

const DB = 
  [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
  , 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20
  , 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30
  , 31, 32, 33
  ]
```

Below we demonstrate running the program. `getAllProducts` is a familiar async function which returns a Promise of its result. We chain a `.then` call so we can see all of the product pages output in the console

```
getAllProducts () .then (console.log, console.error)
// ~2 seconds later
// [ [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
// , [ 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]
// , [ 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 ]
// , [ 16, 17, 18, 19, 20 ]
// , [ 21, 22, 23, 24, 25 ]
// , [ 26, 27, 28, 29, 30 ]
// , [ 31, 32, 33 ]
// ]
```

Instead of grouping products by page, it'd be nice if we could return all the products in a single array. We can modify `getAllProducts` slightly to achieve this

```
const concat = (xs, ys) =>
  xs .concat (ys)

const concatAll = (arrays) =>
  arrays .reduce (concat, [])

const getAllProducts = async (page = 0) =>
  asyncUnfold
    ( ... )
    .then (concatAll)

getAllProducts () .then (console.log, console.error)
// ~2 seconds later
// [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, ..., 31, 32, 33 ]
```

Lastly, we introduce `asyncUnfold`

```
const asyncUnfold = async (f, initState) =>
  f ( async (value, nextState) => [ value, ...await asyncUnfold (f, nextState) ]
    , async () => []
    , initState
    )
```

Full program demonstration

```js
// dependencies -------------------------------------------------
const asyncUnfold = async (f, initState) =>
  f ( async (value, nextState) => [ value, ...await asyncUnfold (f, nextState) ]
    , async () => []
    , initState
    )

const concat = (xs, ys) =>
  xs .concat (ys)
  
const concatAll = (arrays) =>
  arrays .reduce (concat, [])
  

// fakes --------------------------------------------------------
const getProducts = (offset = 0, limit = 1) =>
  Promise.resolve
    ({ json: () =>
        ({ products: DB.slice (offset, offset + limit) })
    })
  .then (delay)

const delay = (x, ms = 250) =>
  new Promise (r => setTimeout (r, ms, x))

const DB = 
  [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
  , 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20
  , 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30
  , 31, 32, 33
  ]

// actual program
const getAllProducts = async (page = 0) =>
  asyncUnfold
    ( async (next, done, [ res, nextPage ]) =>
      res.products.length === 0
          ? done ()
          : next ( res.products
                 , [ await getPage (nextPage), nextPage + 1 ]
                 )
    , [ await getPage (page), page + 1 ]
    )
    .then (concatAll)
    
const getPage = async (page = 0, itemsPerPage = 5) =>
  getProducts (page * itemsPerPage, itemsPerPage)
    .then (res => res.json ())

// demo ---------------------------------------------------------
getAllProducts ()
  .then (console.log, console.error)

// ~2 seconds later
// [ 1, 2, 3, ..., 31, 32, 33 ]
```

Other questions I've answered about recursion and promises

- [*Recursion call async func with promises gets Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49681942/633183)
- [*Recursive JS function with setTimeout*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49523873/633183)
- [*Promise with recursion*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49526214/633183)

Asynchrony and recursion are separate concepts. If you're struggling with `asyncUnfold`, it might help to first understand its synchronous counterpart `unfold`. These Q&A's may help distinguish the two.

- [*Functional way to create an array of numbers*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50109309/633183)
- [*Loop until... with Ramda*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49543489/633183)
- [*Node.js recursively list full path of files*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50122941/633183)

Comment: it's a lot to digest but thank you for your thorough answer!

Comment: I'm happy to help. Let me know if you run into any questions :D

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the return statement inside the else condition

```
function missingItemsPromise() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        if (missingItems == 0) {
            console.log('resolves');
            console.log(products);
            return resolve();
        } else {
            page++;
            url = getUrl(id, page);
            http.get(url, function(xres) {
                xres.setEncoding('utf8');
                xres.on('data', function (xtraBody) {
                    console.log('calling');
                    var xtraJson = JSON.parse(xtraBody);
                    var xtraProducts = xtraJson['products'];
                    products = products.concat(xtraProducts);
                    productsLength = products.length;
                    missingItems = total - productsLength;
                   return  missingItemsPromise(); //this is the line that changes
                });
            });
        } 
    });
};
```

Comment: no change :\ even when I return at that line hello never prints out